# Creating a proper channel for a single process generating more than one fasta

Tags: nextflow

I created a pipeline that starts with *fastq.gz* files and then **process CONSENSUS_BUILDING** creates **one or more** consensus fasta sequences and the **process BLAST** does blast on each. For a given fastq.gz file, when the CONSENSUS_BUILDING process outputs a single consensus sequence it works fine, but when it is more than one I get an error as it creates the wrong command, for example, if a given fastq.gz file leads to three consensus sequences I get the following command:

```
blastn -db references/hAdv_filtered.fasta \ 
  -query consensus_reference_121.fasta consensus_reference_151.fasta consensus_reference_186.fasta \
  -outfmt '6 sseqid stitle pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore' \
  -out [consensus_reference_121, consensus_reference_151, consensus_reference_186].blast
```

How can I fix this so that it does separate BLAST processes for each consensus sequence? Below is my current workflow:

```
process CONSENSUS_BUILDING {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/consensus", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path fastq

    output:
    path "${fastq.getSimpleName()}_ID/*.fasta", emit: consensus_fasta

    script:
    """
    gunzip -f ${fastq}
    NGSpeciesID --ont --sample_size 10000 --consensus --racon --racon_iter 3 --fastq ${fastq.getSimpleName()}.fastq --m\
 650 --s 50 --outfolder ${fastq.getSimpleName()}_ID
    """
}

process BLAST {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/blast", mode: 'copy'
    container  'docker://ncbi/blast'

    input:
    tuple val(sampleID), path(fasta)
    path db

    output:
    path "${sampleID}.blast"

    script:
    """
    blastn -db $db/$db_name -query ${fasta} -outfmt '6 sseqid stitle pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send\
 evalue bitscore' -out ${sampleID}.blast
    """
}


// Overall workflow
workflow {
    ch_reads = Channel.fromPath( "${params.reads}/*.fastq.gz" )
    ch_consensus = CONSENSUS_BUILDING(ch_reads)
    CONSENSUS_BUILDING
      .out
      .consensus_fasta
      .map{ it -> tuple(it.simpleName, it) }
      .set{ blast_in }
    ch_blast = BLAST(blast_in, db_dir)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier if you ensure that only 1 file is passed from `CONSENSUS_BUILDING` to `BLAST`, which you could do by ensuring that you use the `flatten` [operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#flatten), but given the script I would have expected it to be emitting only 1 file per process anyway. Note, you should put `flatten` before the `map` operator if this is how you choose to move forward.

Otherwise you can define a function for elastic input handling. Here is an example for `BLAST`:

```
process BLAST {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/blast", mode: 'copy'
    container  'docker://ncbi/blast'

    input:
    tuple val(sampleID), path(fasta)
    path db

    output:
    path "${sampleID}.blast"

    script:
    def elastic_blast = fasta.collect{ "newname=`basename $it | sed "s/.fasta//"; blastn -db $db/$db_name -query $it -outfmt '6 sseqid stitle pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue bitscore' -out \${newname}.blast }.join("\n")
    """
    ${elastic_blast}
    """
}
```

Code not tested, so may need some debugging. I'm also unsure what your input tuples would look like for `BLAST` if `CONSENSUS_BUILDING` is outputting multiple fastas in one object. Is it `[consensus_121, [consensus_reference_121.fasta, consensus_reference_151.fasta, consensus_reference_186.fasta,]]`? However, since you're using bash to generate the sample ID variable called `newname`, you could remove the `map` operator from the workflow, and change the input declaration for `BLAST` to just `path(fasta)` and this would still work.

Finally, I'm also unsure if you need the `collect` in the `def` block, but it's how I've always used it.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Indeed flatten() did the trick just fine!